# Merge array recursively in extended class

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have the following code in php:

```
<?php
interface someInterface {
    public function foo();
}

class A implements someInterface {
    public function foo(){
        return [
            'a' => 'some value',
            'b' => 'some value',
            'c' => [
                'ca' => 'some value',
                'cb' => 'some value',
                'cc' => 'some value'
            ]
        ];
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo(){
        return [
            'a' => 'some value 2',
            'c' => [
                'ca' => 'some value 3',
                'cb' => 'some value 4'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Doing the following

```
$b = new B();
var_dump($b->foo());
```

must give me the following output

```
[
    'a' => 'some value 2',
    'b' => 'some value',
    'c' => [
        'ca' => 'some value 3',
        'cb' => 'some value 4',
        'cc' => 'some value'
    ]
]
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Anyone can extend `class A` and I don't want other users to manually use `array_merge_recursive` for achieving this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a loop in the `b > foo` where you call the parent `foo`. You can merge it then manually with a `for` or `foreach` loop.

Comment: May be I was not clear. Anyone can extend `class A` and I don't want them to write any extra code.

Comment: You want to prevent them for overwriting the `foo` function?

Comment: No. The overridden `foo` must return merged array

Comment: Yes, so you create your own merge function in `b > foo`, which merge the array of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a class in the middle that does the work. It should have another method that will be inherited and later used. The only condition here is to not use `foo()` in public, but `getFoo()` instead

```
interface someInterface {
    public function foo();
}


class A implements someInterface {
    public function foo(){
        return [
            'a' => 'some value',
            'b' => 'some value',
            'c' => [
                'ca' => 'some value',
                'cb' => 'some value',
                'cc' => 'some value'
            ]
        ];
    }
}

class Middle extends A {
    public function getFoo() {
        return array_merge_recursive(parent::foo(), $this->foo());
    }
}

class B extends Middle {
    public function foo(){
        return [
            'a' => 'some value 2',
            'c' => [
                'ca' => 'some value 3',
                'cb' => 'some value 4'
            ]
        ];
    }
}

$b = new B();
var_dump($b->getFoo());
```

This could also be achieved making `foo()` protected and a magic `__call()` method which does the work of `getFoo()`. Then calling `$b->foo()` will trigger `__call()` thus resulting in merging that `parent` and `this` contexts of `foo()` and spitting them out.

By the way, array merge recursive will not result into the exactly the same output you do want, anyway, you can do whatever logic you need in `getFoo()` (or in `__call()`)

A problem here could be that if `foo()` has lower access modifier than `public` you cannot have it in an interface. Luckily, abstract classes could have abstract protected methods which will obligate the childred to implement this method.

A sample scenario of the `__call()` way and obligating members to have `protected foo()` could be:

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract protected function foo();
}

abstract class A {
    protected function foo(){
        return [
            'a' => 'some value',
            'b' => 'some value',
            'c' => [
                'ca' => 'some value',
                'cb' => 'some value',
                'cc' => 'some value'
            ]
        ];
    }
}

class Middle extends A {
    public function __call($name, $args) {
        if ($name == 'foo')
            return array_merge_recursive(parent::foo(), $this->foo());
    }
}

class B extends Middle {
    protected function foo(){
        return [
            'a' => 'some value 2',
            'c' => [
                'ca' => 'some value 3',
                'cb' => 'some value 4'
            ]
        ];
    }
}

$b = new B();
var_dump($b->foo());
```

This way `B` will have some problems with autocompletion of foo.
If One does not know the "hack" when writing `$b->` will not recieve suggestion for `foo()`.
A little more hacks can resolve this in at least `Netbeans` and `PHPStorm`

Annotating that `Middle` has a public `foo()` method before definition of `Middle` class:

```
/**
 * @method foo
 */
class Middle extends A {
```

Later annotating that the instance of `B` is actually an instance of `Middle`:

```
$b = new B();
/* @var $b Middle */
```

Afterwards writing `$b->` will result into suggesting the `foo()` method.

It might be better if there is another class that inherits `B` and has no methods, but only annotations, but as I understood, classes like `B` will be written from other people and they might not be familiar with this convention.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I just made some edits for more information :) Let me know if something is unclear or if it worked for you :)

Comment: I tried `_call` without interface but keep getting error as `Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent` -> [gist here](https://gist.github.com/vkbansal/f0133e365abb44d7e03c)

Comment: Where did you try it? There should be a middle class that has parent which has `foo()`. That's the purpose of `class Middle`

Comment: I tried in my local machine with wamp installed. [Here's the code I tested](https://gist.github.com/vkbansal/f0133e365abb44d7e03c)

Comment: Yes, this code will not work as expected, because `__call()` is called from parent context which has no parent, the `__call()` method should be in between your child and your base class, as shown in `class Middle` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62223/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-bansal-and-royal-bg).

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

```
<?php

interface someInterface
{
    public function foo();
}

class A implements someInterface
{
    public function foo()
    {
        return [
            'a' => 'some value',
            'b' => 'some value',
            'c' => [
                'ca' => 'some value',
                'cb' => 'some value',
                'cc' => 'some value'
            ]
        ];
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function foo()
    {
        $parent = parent::foo();
        $arr = [

            'a' => 'some value 2',
            'c' => [
                'ca' => 'some value 3',
                'cb' => 'some value 4'
            ]
        ];


        return $this->mergeArrays($arr, $parent);

    }

    private function mergeArrays($ar1, $ar2)
    {
        foreach ($ar1 as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                if (isset($ar2[$key])) {
                    $ar2[$key] = $this->mergeArrays($item, $ar2[$key]);
                } else {
                    $ar2[$key] = $item;
                }
            } else {
                $ar2[$key] = $item;
            }
        }
        return $ar2;
    }

}


$b = new B();
var_dump($b->foo());
```

Output:

> array(3) { ["a"]=> string(12) "some value 2" ["b"]=> string(10) "some
>   value" ["c"]=> array(3) { ["ca"]=> string(12) "some value 3" ["cb"]=>
>   string(12) "some value 4" ["cc"]=> string(10) "some value" } }

Comment: I've tried this but this isn't the solution I'm looking for. I want it to be automated. Can something be done using __call()?

Comment: @VivekKumarBansal What do you mean "automated" ? You wanted your function `foo` to return such result and it does it

Comment: I mean if I create a `class C` that extends `class B`. Then `C::foo` must also return a merged array without me manually writing `$this->mergeArrays($arr, $parent);`

Comment: @VivekKumarBansal There is no such option I'm afraid